# Return Uniqueidentifier from CLR Function

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2008-r2, clr

I am creating a CLR function for SQL Server 2008 R2.  The CLR function returns an `uniqueidentifier`, which can sometimes be `null`.  It works when the return value is **not** `null`.  However, when a `null` value is returned, SQL Server throws the error `Specified cast is not valid.`

The function is registered in the database with:

```
create function MyFunc returns uniqueidentifier as external name AssemblyName.UserDefinedFunctions.MyFunc
```

### Example Code

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static Guid MyFunc()
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
  {
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandText = "select cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)";
      //cmd.CommandText = "select cast(null as uniqueidentifier)";
      return (Guid)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
  }
}
```

The first `CommandText` works, the second throws the `Specified cast is not valid` error.

I tried changing the return type from `Guid` to `SqlGuid` on lines 2 and 12, but then SQL Server always throws the `Specified cast is not valid` error, regardless whether the value is `null` or not.

### Question

What is the proper way to return a `uniqueidentifier` from a CLR function when the return value is sometimes `null`?

Comment: Can I ask why you're going out to CLR to execute T-SQL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - For this particular project, we have placed as much T-SQL into CLR DLLs as possible.  We can use a T-SQL Function if needed.  Is that what you are suggesting?  Can it be done with CLR?

Comment: It just seems odd to put T-SQL into CLR, especially even more so "as much as possible"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - We have dozens of databases where the SQL is used, and have an automatic method of re-registering the CLR DLLs in the databases.  So deploying CLR code is effortless.  We haven't built a deployment system for T-SQL code yet...

Comment: Are all the databases on the same server? If so why not use a centralized function instead of one per database? Also you should be aware that most T-SQL functionality (e.g. data access) performed within CLR is actually less efficient than the same operations without going through CLR. Whether the convenience you cite outweighs performance, *shrug*, but you should test it if performance is a concern.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks for your comments, good things to consider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL Server uniqueidentifier returns a binary structure which cannot be explicitly cast to the `Guid` .NET datatype.

See here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ab55037d-6c62-405d-8cac-9e902d867b78 where the solution is to cast it to a byte[] (what it really is) and create a new Guid from it.

```
Guid g = new Guid(cmd.ExecuteScalar() as byte[]);
```

Of course, you need to test whether `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is null and create Guid.Empty instead.

I had assumed that your T-SQL code is for demonstration purposes only and you are generating GUIDs using some other purpose.  If on the other hand you just need a unique GUID from within SQL Server, you could just use the NEWID() built in function.

```
select NEWID()
```

Comment: Yes.  The T-SQL was just for demonstration purposes.  Thank you for your answer.  That makes sense...